# Accumulation Point of S

Tags: real-analysis

Let $S = [{(-1)^n+ \frac{1}{n}}$] and $n \in \mathbb{N}$

Find the accumulation point of S.

I don't think there are any, but I am not sure. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: sure there are.  There are 2.

Comment: Knowing that, what do you suppose they would be?

Comment: Why to you think $1$ is not an accumulation point?

Comment: OK, what do you suppose the *other* one would be? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$1$ and $-1$ are accumulation point of $S$.

take the subsequence formed by the even terms.

$a_{2n} = 1+\frac{1}{n} \to 1$ so $1$ is an accumulation point

take the subsequence formed by the odd terms.

$a_{2n+1} = -1+\frac{1}{n} \to -1$ so $-1$ is an accumulation point